# Coin Purse Program

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I'm working through this java book and have come across an exercise I cannot seem to solve. The idea is to create an ArrayList Purse with however many coins in it and print it's reverse out. I have added...

```
static String d = "Dime";
static String q = "Quarter";
static String n = "Nickel";

purse.addCoin(d);
purse.addCoin(q);
purse.addCoin(d);
purse.addCoin(n);
```

...in my main class. My print method works fine, I just need to figure out how to approach reversing all of the elements in the array list and then printing it. My reverse loop works great in terms of looping through the array list from the very end, but I am not sure how to remove the unwanted elements. I am obviously open to approaching this differently as I am looking to do this the correct way. Here is my reverse method:

```
 public static void printInReverse() {
    for (int i = p.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        p.add(p.get(i));
        //I'm lost here as far as approaching the method this way

    }

    System.out.println("Purse" + p);
}
```

I have tried to research this but can't seem to find a reliable solution.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do. If you're just trying to print the elements in reverse there's no need to remove them.

Comment: There actually is no need to remove them as I have discovered from everyone's replies. I was approaching it in a much more complicated way than it should have been.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is there any reason you need to *remove* things from the list?  Just print in reverse, don't actually modify the list.

   for (int i = p.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

   ```
   System.out.println(p.get(i));
   ```

   }
2. If you want to reverse the list - consider just making a *new* list from scratch with elements inserted in the reverse order.  Then swap out the old list for the new one.  Or use `Collections.reverse`.

Comment: Excellent points made by all of you. I wasn't aware of the Collections class though. That is rather handy. Creating a new list and using the new one seems like the most efficient way to have a list that is actually reversed. Is there a benefit to using Collections.reverse versus creating a new list? Thanks everyone for replying. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that reversing `p` while looping through it is a bad idea. If `p` is a list, then `Collections.reverse(p)` will reverse it. To stay in the safe side, make a copy of `p` and reverse that!

See this: 
http://www.java-examples.com/reverse-order-all-elements-java-arraylist-example

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply to print out all of the elements in reverse, you could just simply loop through your array in reverse, and print out the items as you iterate through them.